# How is replaced struct tcp_opt in the newer kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I working on an old module for kernel 2.4.x and want to rewrite it for kernel 4.15.0.19.

There is a declaration which is causing an error during the compilation:

```
struct tcp_opt *tp = &(sk->tp_pinfo.af_tcp);
```

I checked in the newer kernel and tcp_opt struct is not defined anywhere, neither tp_pinfo union nor af_tcp.

From 2.4.x kernel, it is declared inside struct sock as follows:

```
    union {
    struct tcp_opt      af_tcp;
    #if defined(CONFIG_INET) || defined (CONFIG_INET_MODULE)
    struct raw_opt      tp_raw4;
    #endif
    #if defined(CONFIG_IPV6) || defined (CONFIG_IPV6_MODULE)
    struct raw6_opt     tp_raw;
    #endif /* CONFIG_IPV6 */
    #if defined(CONFIG_SPX) || defined (CONFIG_SPX_MODULE)
    struct spx_opt      af_spx; 
    #endif /* CONFIG_SPX */

} tp_pinfo;
```

What is the purpose of the first initialisation (in the beginning of the question) and how is this replaced in the newer kernels?

---

EDIT:

I managed to solve this using:

```
const struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);
```

And then accessing the TCP Options in this way:

```
tp->rx_opt.rcv_tsval
```